# How to move partition next to C drive (in order to extend drive C)

Tags: windows, partitioning, easeus-partition-manager

I am trying to extend my drive C with 34GB unallocated space on my SSD (see the image below) however, I am unable to do so. I have tried software such as EaseUS Partition Master and MiniTool Partition Wizard to **Extend** or **Merge** the two (I have tried to create a new partition out of the unallocated space before Extend and Merge commands as well). I would appreciate any suggestion. Thank you in advance!

PS.: my system is due boot - Windows 10 and Linux (Solus OS).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do that is by moving the 3 small partitions (846MB, 2.8GB, 32.2GB) to the end of the drive, so that the Unallocated space comes right after C. The space used by a partition must be contiguous - you cannot create partitions from chunks scattered across the drive.

You are lucky enough to have the 3 partitions smaller than the Unallocated space, so in theory you can move them to the right one by one (first 32.2Gb, then 2.8GB, then 846MB). If "Move" is not an option in your partition editor, you can try to clone them into the empty space and then delete the old partition.

Word of caution though:
1. if I were you, I would simply backup the Linux installation and move it to a VirtualBox instance, then use all the space that I need.
2. because that is an SSD, it is quite healthy to leave that space unallocated: it is called over-provisioning and it can help increase the lifetime of the disk

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! I ended up reinstalling Windows 10 as it broke down on me (I was on the Insider programme) so I had a chance to do the partitions the way I wanted.